# How to get div to extend past floated images

Tags: css, background

Hey I am trying to get the opacity bacground I made in CSS to extend to the bottom of my images, when I do a text float left or right.

**CSS**

```
.gamebackground {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px 50px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:80%;
  height:10%;
  background-color:Black;
  z-index:1;
  /* These three lines are for transparency in all browsers. */
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity:.5;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="gamebackground"></div>
<img src="images/download.jpg"width=50% class="floatRight">
  text
</div>
```

I did it a few years ago but I have forgotten, if you could help me out that would be very appreciated! thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to have the `</div>` before the image and text?

Comment: Yeah its just dropping the background behind the text.

Comment: Sorry guys finally figured it out.

Comment: .content {
  position:absolute;
  color:White;
  z-index:5;
  padding: 15px;  
  background-color: rgba(0,0,5,0.5);
}

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Since you solved it yourself, you should post what worked (preferably with some explanation) as an answer and then accept it.  It makes it easier for other people to find, sticks out more than the comments, and the extra rep won't hurt ;)